# fetch() Not setting cookie despite `Set-Cookie` header

Tags: cookies, fetch-api

My backend-api written in Node and Express.js sets a cookie using `res.cookie`:

```
Router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    try {
        let result = await sqlite.login(email, password);
        res.cookie('token', result, {
            'maxAge': 3600 * 1000
        });
        res.send({
            'token' : result
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
});
```

I can make a request to this route, and I do notice the `Set-Cookie` header is set on the response object within Chrome developer tools:

```
Set-Cookie: token=[...]; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 11 Jul 2022 14:47:08 GMT
```

However, `document.cookie` is never set by the browser. From my searching, most people say to specify the `credentials` field as `same-origin`. I have done this and it made no change. My cookie is NOT being set as HttpOnly, so I am unsure why it's being set by the browser.

Here is where I call the `/login` route:

```
async login(email, password) {
        let response = await fetch(apiURL + '/login', {
            'method' : 'POST',
            'headers' : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                'Accept' : 'application/json'
            },
            'credentials' : 'same-origin',
            'body' : JSON.stringify({
                'email' : email,
                'password' : password
            })
        });

        return await response.json();
    }
```

A token is successfully returned in the response, but again `document.cookie` returns an empty string `''`.

From searching this problem, most of the issues seem to suggest that `same-origin` should fix the issue but it is not the case for myself. Another thing of note is that httpOnly cookies won't show in the browser, but I know that the cookies I am sending are not HttpOnly.

I am using Google Chrome version 103.0.5060.114.

If I set `credentials` to `include`, I get a CORS error:

```
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working with the following changes:
When initializing npm package `cors`, specify some options:

```
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: 'http://lvh.me:3001' }));
```

The origin *must* include the `http://` prefix as well as the correct port. Once that was done, set `credentials` to `include`  when calling `fetch()` and it should work fine.